# While trying to merge two matrices i'm getting a ref error. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Tags: excel, vba, function

```
Public Function v2(LeftMatrix As Range, RightMatrix As Range) As Variant()

Dim e As Integer, s As Integer

e = LeftMatrix.Rows.Count
s = LeftMatrix.Columns.Count


ReDim m(1 To e, 1 To s + 1)

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

For i = 1 To e
  For j = 1 To s + 1
    If j <= s Then
      m(i, j) = LeftMatrix(i, j)
    Else
      m(i, j) = RightMatrix(i, 1)
  Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To e
  For j = 1 To s + 1

    Cells(i, j) = m(i, j)

  Next j
Next i
End Function
```

I'm selecting two matrices from my worksheet and trying to merge them into a single matrix but I keep getting the ref error.

Comment: Are you trying to call this from a cell?

Comment: where do you initially declare `m` and what are `k_m` and `l_n`?

Comment: yes, im selecting a cell in the worksheet

Comment: Here is a function that does what you are trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655098/replicate-google-sheets-array1-array2-function-in-microsoft-excel-as-user-def/68655804#68655804  It works with any number of ranges.  The only caveat is that they all must have the same number of columns.  It takes any number of ranges and returns an array of those ranges stacked on top of each other.

Comment: BTW, you cannot do: `Cells(i, j) = m(i, j)` in a function called from the worksheet.  Function called from the work sheet cannot change the value of other cells.  If you have office 365 just return the array itself and it will spill the results.  But you need to `Dim` the array before you `ReDim`.

Comment: Also a visual representation of what you have and what you are trying to achieve will help.

Comment: BTW, if you have Office 365 the following formula will do what you want: `=LET(leftrng,$A$1:$D$17,rightrng,K1:K17,CHOOSE(INT(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(leftrng)+1,0)/COLUMNS(leftrng)+1),leftrng,rightrng))`  Where `$A$1:$D$17` is the left range and `K1:K17` is the right range.