# Combine stack columns into one single column

Tags: excel, filter, merge, array-merge

**Problem**

I am looking for a way to stack values from multiple columns into one. I need to ensure that all values, including duplicates are added. I'm not too fussed if the order is changed, but all values need to be included. I'm aware of `CONCAT`, but I am not attempting to merge multiple columns into one row horizontally, I am attempting to merge them vertically.

**Example Table**

(I am unable to save this as a table, SO tells me I must format my code, despite it not being code. anyone who has permissions to change this back into a table, I would appreciate it)

| A | B | A&B Merge |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Cheese | Foo |
| Bar | Oranges | Bar |
| Baz | Pear | Baz |
| Qux | Banana | Qux |
| Quux | Grape | Quux |
| Corge |  | Corge |
|  |  | Cheese |
|  |  | Oranges |
|  |  | Pear |
|  |  | Banana |
|  |  | Grape |

**Summary**
I am unsure on how to merge these two columns vertically into one column, instead of combining the data together (I always end up with `FooBanana` for example). Any assistance or guidance
would be appreciated.

**Extra**

I am looking to filter formula the output column. I'm very familiar with `FILTER`, and I was just planning on running my `FILTER` on the output column, but if there's different way of approaching this problem accounting for the output needing to be put through `FILTER`, that would be great, but not necessary.

The stacking will need to be completed in multiple versions of Excel including 2016. The `=FILTER` work will be done exclusively within MSO 365.

Thanks!

Comment: Just the fact that you want to use FILTER makes this a vba problem as FILTER does not exist in Excel 2016

Comment: Here is a UDF that will stack ranges: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655098/replicate-google-sheets-array1-array2-function-in-microsoft-excel-as-user-def

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified further - I'll edit the question. The data itself needs to be merged in versions of Excel 2016, but the `=FILTER` work will be done exclusively in another sheet within MSO365, with no backwards compatibility needed.

Comment: Stacking can be done with `VSTACK()` and/or `TOCOL()`

Comment: ScottCraner - thank you. Although, due to some irritating policies, running macros generally isn't possible. I am looking for a formula that can accomplish this instead if possible. I tried to edit the question to specify a formula, but ran into the "question contains code" issue again. 

@JvdV - I don't seem to have access to these functions - company restricts the installed version to 2108, unfortunately. I suppose I'm out of luck here? Thanks again both for your help and suggestions.