# Excel Dynamic Array Dynamically placed under another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Use Case: Golf irrigation valve assembly ordering. My boss said:

> Hey [piratecheese13], I don't want this part summary to include blanks between [dynamic arrays] and I want to add and remove things to the [precedent to the array]

**I have suggested inserting and deleting rows as needed. This is not a solution.** She wants to get my list, add and remove rows from the precedent to the array, and send it to a vendor for ordering. Any work she does beyond that, is work she'd rather I do before it gets to her.

I have a neat little Dynamic Array function `=FILTER(PartsAndQuantities1,(Parts1<>"")*(IF(Quantities1=0,"",Quantities1)<>""))`and it works flawlessly to summarize while removing 0 counts and blank rows. The next step is to insert the same exact formula for a different range **without risking a spill if a row is added or a blank if a row is removed**

[Here's that function in green working as intended with a 2nd function in red manually typed below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OcOx.png)

[Here's what happens if my boss decides to remove a fitting from F9. She sees a blank in the summary a half hour later and assumes there was an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmeFI.png). Again, easily solved by removing a row but that's not an option.

[Here's what happens if my boss decides to add a fitting to F12. She sees #Spill! and knows there is an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUcV.png) Again, easily solved by inserting rows but that's not an option.

Things I Have Attempted:

Just stick an `&` Between 2 functions. I really thought this would work but
[this results in `F7&F18 and G7&G18 etc`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8iKa.png) as & appears to do work on every line instead of starting after the first `FILTER()` completes. adding parentheticals around each filter changes nothing. Using `+` results in value error. Nesting the function within `AND()` only ever results in Booleans `TRUE & FALSE`

I've also tried [this tutorial on `CHOOSE()` which handles multiple arrays but only one column and seems like it wouldn't fit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qZ8ud8akus)

Note: my boss doesn't want to insert lines to solve spill errors, she REALY doesn't want to deal with macro enabled workbooks

Comment: Do you have VSTACK, yet?  It is a new formula that is being released to some so far.

Comment: If not here is a udf that kind of does the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655098/replicate-google-sheets-array1-array2-function-in-microsoft-excel-as-user-def

Comment: @ScottCraner there's no sample data, no expected output, no indication of what errors they're getting with their current approach. Images and links to external resources must be supplementary – the question has to stand on its own without them.

Comment: @miken32 with Excel formula, many times the only way to show what is going wrong is with a picture.  There is enough verbiage in the question for those who frequent the Excel-Formula tag to know what the issue is.  I did not even need to open the pictures to know the problem.  The pictures helped solidify, but this question could stand on it's own with out them.

Comment: No I'm not active in the tag, I just came across it because the answer was auto-flagged as possibly problematic. I didn't downvote but did cast my close vote based on the standards set for the site as a whole.

Comment: @miken32 I do appreciate your willingness to work through the review queues and your willingness to engage my questions.  And I tend in general to agree with your points above.  I personally just feel the close was not the correct response in this specific instance, and have cast my vote in that direction.  we will see if I get one more to agree with me or not. :) And I will probably be yelled at by the mods because this discussion should probably be in meta.

Answer (score 1):

[Thanks to Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) this was exactly what I needed!

`=VSTACK(FILTER(F7:G15,(F7:F15<>"")*(IF(G7:G15=0,"",G7:G15)<>"")),FILTER(F17:G23,(F17:F23<>"")*(IF(G17:G23=0,"",G17:G23)<>"")))`
[image: In green here]